# Format date as user types to MM/DD/YYYY in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hello i working on a react native app where a user enters their date via Textinput but as the user types i would like to format the date to MM/DD/YYYY. So far i have this function

```
    const formatDate(value: string) => {
     if(!value) return ''
     if(value.lastIndexOf('/') !== -1) {
       value = value.substring(0, value.length-1)
     } else if(value.length === 2 || value.length === 5) 
      {
       value += '/'
     }
     return value
}
```

It work fines when entering values and not deleting. But if a user attempts to delete their date it works incorrectly. My issue is when a user attempts to delete a character. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

while you certainly can achieve that on your own, I'd suggest that you give one of the "input masking" libraries a try they should work great for your case.

You could also explore the option of using date pickers instead of text input, or splitting your text input into 3 separate text inputs and let the cursor jump between the 3 based on certain conditions (ex: jump from day to month input after the user adds the second integer, or jump from year to month when the user deletes the year value)

Comment: thanks for the response what masking library do you advise using?

Comment: react-native-text-input-mask works for me for most cases, yet to see  a library that does everything correctly, but this one is good for simple cases like this

Comment: thanks will take a look at the library